# celery multi start PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/run/celery'

Tags: python, linux, permissions, celery, celery-task

I'm trying to run celery multi workers for a specific group of task with the command

```
celery multi start proj.main -E
```

but when I execute it got me this permission error

```
celery multi start proj.main -E
celery multi v5.2.3 (dawn-chorus)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/developer/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/envs/CeleryRabbit/bin/celery", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/developer/.pyenv/versions/CeleryRabbit/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 15, in main
    sys.exit(_main())
  File "/home/developer/.pyenv/versions/CeleryRabbit/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 213, in main
    return celery(auto_envvar_prefix="CELERY")
  File "/home/developer/.pyenv/versions/CeleryRabbit/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1128, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/developer/.pyenv/versions/CeleryRabbit/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1053, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/developer/.pyenv/versions/CeleryRabbit/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1659, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/developer/.pyenv/versions/CeleryRabbit/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1395, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/developer/.pyenv/versions/CeleryRabbit/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/developer/.pyenv/versions/CeleryRabbit/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 26, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/developer/.pyenv/versions/CeleryRabbit/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 134, in caller
    return f(ctx, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/developer/.pyenv/versions/CeleryRabbit/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/bin/multi.py", line 480, in multi
    return cmd.execute_from_commandline(args)
  File "/home/developer/.pyenv/versions/CeleryRabbit/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/bin/multi.py", line 271, in execute_from_commandline
    return self.call_command(argv[0], argv[1:])
  File "/home/developer/.pyenv/versions/CeleryRabbit/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/bin/multi.py", line 278, in call_command
    return self.commands[command](*argv) or EX_OK
  File "/home/developer/.pyenv/versions/CeleryRabbit/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/bin/multi.py", line 148, in _inner
    return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/developer/.pyenv/versions/CeleryRabbit/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/bin/multi.py", line 156, in _inner
    return fun(self, self.cluster_from_argv(argv), **kwargs)
  File "/home/developer/.pyenv/versions/CeleryRabbit/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/bin/multi.py", line 366, in cluster_from_argv
    _, cluster = self._cluster_from_argv(argv, cmd=cmd)
  File "/home/developer/.pyenv/versions/CeleryRabbit/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/bin/multi.py", line 371, in _cluster_from_argv
    return p, self.Cluster(list(nodes), cmd=cmd)
  File "/home/developer/.pyenv/versions/CeleryRabbit/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/apps/multi.py", line 319, in <genexpr>
    self._node_from_options(
  File "/home/developer/.pyenv/versions/CeleryRabbit/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/apps/multi.py", line 328, in _node_from_options
    return Node(nodename, cmd, append,
  File "/home/developer/.pyenv/versions/CeleryRabbit/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/apps/multi.py", line 132, in __init__
    self.options = self._annotate_with_default_opts(
  File "/home/developer/.pyenv/versions/CeleryRabbit/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/apps/multi.py", line 140, in _annotate_with_default_opts
    self._setdefaultopt(options, ['--pidfile', '-p'], '/var/run/celery/%n.pid')
  File "/home/developer/.pyenv/versions/CeleryRabbit/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/apps/multi.py", line 154, in _setdefaultopt
    os.makedirs(dir_path)
  File "/home/developer/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 225, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/run/celery'
```

I didn't get this error if I execute differents workers in differents terminals

my project structure is:

```
proj
     __init__.py
     celeryconfig.py
     main.py
     tasks.py
```

how can I use multi my celery version is v5.2.3

**my celeryconfig.py**

```
# config for proj celery
broker_url = 'pyamqp://'
result_backend = 'rpc://'

task_serializer = 'json'
result_serializer = 'json'
accept_content = ['json']
timezone = 'America/Caracas'
enable_utc = True
include = ['proj.tasks']
task_ignore_result = True
```

**my main.py**

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('proj')

app.conf.update(result_expires=3600)

app.config_from_object("proj.celeryconfig")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

**tasks.py**

```
import random
import time

from .main import app


@app.task
def too_long_task(n):
    t = random.randint(4, 8)
    time.sleep(t)
    return f"task n:{n} long task done"


@app.task
def quick_task(n):
    t = random.randint(0, 3)
    time.sleep(t)
    return f"task n:{n} quick task done"


@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y


@app.task
def mul(x, y):
    return x * y


@app.task
def rest(x, y):
    return x - y


@app.task
def n_add(numbers):
    return sum(numbers)
```